# (Python) Print all '\' escape characters

Tags: python, replace, escaping

I have several strings with `\` in it. I try to not using escape characters by using the replace function like that:

```
string.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

It does not work.

When I use `string.replace("\n", "\\n")` for `\n` directly it works.
Is there an easy working solution for that?

Comment: If you're trying to replace `\n`, then `replace("\\"` is not going to work, because `\n` not the same as ```\``` followed by `n`. It is a single newline character.

Comment: Try parsing `repr` of the string.

Comment: string.replace("\n", "\\n") essentially replaces the newline character with the string "\n", but the newline character itself does not contain the backslash, so string.replace("\\", "\\\\") will never replace newlines, tabs or anything else that looks like something containing a backslash, but actually not.

Comment: @Ch3steR That works, although i have the ' at the beginning and start now: Maybe I print string[1:-1] then?

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that replace does not act on the variable but rather returns a copy with the replacement applied See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
this = "string\\string"
this.replace("\\", "")

print(this)
>"string\\string"
```

If you want the original string to be replaced,

```
this = this.replace("\\", "")
```

However, to convert `\n -> n` would require that you think differently about this. i.e. `replace('\n', 'n')`, as `\n` is a  **single** character.

Comment: No I want to print/write any \ character in the string. When i change it to a raw string it still escapes the \ character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def test():
    foo = r"this is a \\ and this is a \ "
    foo = foo.replace("\\" , r'\\') # added the r to ignore string escapes as escapes

    print(foo)

test()
```

output:

```
this is a \\\\ and this is a \\
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [raw strings](https://www.codevscolor.com/python-raw-string/).

```
r"This \ string \ includes '\'s"
```

Comment: I tried using this `name_parsed = r'%s'%string` for formatting the string as a raw string, but that does not work. When i write the string to a file using csv.writer it still escapes the \ character.